# How to set two interchangeably visible containers in PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I will have radio button with enabled events. Based on the selected value I want one of container of the elements be made visible and the other invisible. I know also there an attribute visible for all elements, I just want to do it on a group of elements, not just one.

I know about the column element, however my two containers are supposed to be on the same horizontal position.

An example of what elements would be in the container:

```
    [sg.InputText(size=(50, 1), key='-FILENAME-'), sg.FileBrowse()],
    [sg.Button("Train", key="-train-")],
    [sg.ProgressBar(1, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progress')],
    [sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS-', size=(200, 200))],
    [sg.InputText(size=(50, 1), default_text="0.5", key='anomaly_threshold'),sg.Button("Decide Threshold",key="-anomaly_threshold-")],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sg.Column` as two containers and put them on the same row in your layout. Switching option `visible` of columns between True and False.

Example Code,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

radio_tag = ["Next", "PREV"]

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 11))

cols = [
    [[sg.Text("Next element is sg.Input", size=(28, 1)), sg.Input()]],
    [[sg.Input(), sg.Text("Previous element is sg.Input", size=(28, 1))]],
]

layout =[
    [sg.Radio(text, "position", default=(i==0), enable_events=True, key=text)
        for i, text in enumerate(radio_tag)],
    [sg.Column(cols[i], visible=(i==0), key=f'COL {i}') for i in range(2)],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in radio_tag:
        for i in range(2):
            window[f'COL {i}'].update(visible=values[radio_tag[i]])

window.close()
```